# Add a restriction to the moodle quiz to restrict attempting it for 24 hours after attempting and failing first quiz

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I need to add a restriction on Exam B - Student can take exam B only after failing Exam A and after 24 hours. I have tried adding one restriction., ie to be able to take exam B only after failing Exam A.I am thinking of implementing this by adding a user override when the student fails.I am still trying to figure out the best approach to do this.I haven't still figured out how to use the override of a user in quiz properly.

[image: example of quizes]

Below is the code snippet to create a new override when the student fails

```
if( $result == 'fail')
{
 
 $data->quiz=$quiz_id;

 $data->userid = $user_id;
 
  $data->timeopen=time();
 $newitemid = $DB->insert_record('quiz_overrides', $data);
 echo $newitemid;
}
```

I am getting error below.

Warning: Use of undefined constant quiz_id - assumed 'quiz_id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/lms/local/leadcenter/lib.php on line 94

Comment: You need to prefix quid_id with $ :) $quiz_id

Comment: Done that . And a new warning appears.Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/lms/local/leadcenter/lib.php

Comment: $data= new \stdClass(); fixed my issue.